# Send different ranges of cells from Excel to different people

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have to send parts of an Excel file via Outlook.
After scanning the network, I encountered the following code.

What I want to improve is that each of the selected addresses receives a different range of cells. Is it possible with a list?

How can I modify the code?

For example:
first selected address receives cells A5 to K 20,
second selected address receives cells A 24 to K 50
etc.

```vb
Sub Report()

    Dim Source As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim cell As Object
    
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the arresses list:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    
    For Each cell In xRg

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Union(Range("D5:K6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("D13:K57").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display  'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
    Next cell
End Sub
```